# Is it possible to create package outside of GOROOT or GOPATH?

Tags: go

My goal is to create a Go's project folder on Desktop `/Users/username/Desktop/Learn/golang-package` and create a `math` package.

Reference: https://www.golang-book.com/books/intro/11

The problem is: `go run main.go` throws `main.go:4:2: package chapter-11/math is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/chapter11/math)`

What I've did:

1. run `go env -w GO111MODULE=off` then `go run main.go`, it throws

   ```
   main.go:4:2: cannot find package "chapter11/math" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/chapter11/math (from $GOROOT)
        /Users/username/go/src/chapter11/math (from $GOPATH)
   ```
2. run `go install` in the `./math` folder, nothing happened.
3. copy `./math` folder to `/usr/local/go/src/chapter11/` and run `go run main.go` it works but I wish to be able to put it on Desktop instead of /usr/local/go where I need to enter the password every time I need to create a new folder or change the folder name.

The folder overview

```
golang-package
|-main.go
|-chapter11
  |- math
     |- math.go
```

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "chapter11/math"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    xs := []float64{1, 2, 3, 4}
    avg := math.Average(xs)
    fmt.Println(avg)
}
```

math.go

```
package math

func Average(xs []float64) float64 {
    total := float64(0)
    for _, x := range xs {
        total += x
    }
    return total / float64(len(xs))
}
```

Comment: You can. Is it a good idea? No. It's 2022 not 2014. Use modules only.. Updating the import paths is a few keystrokes or one invocation of sed. No need to play it hard. And please stop that `go run main.go` crap: Do not use go run with filename arguments..

Comment: Would you care to explain why we should not use `go run main.go`?

Comment: Its a loaded footgun. The second you have more than two files you are going to botch it up. Unfortunately not in the simple cases so you will have a damn hard time to debug the problem. Doing `go run` (no arguments at all) is _safe_ and _less_ to type. Everyone who recommends to use go run main.go doesn't understand what go run does.

Comment: I tried to do `go run` and it throws `go: no go files listed`. Also, regarding `Use modules only`, do you mean that I should write my package on `usr/local/go/src/chapter11/math/`? If so, I would but I need to keep enter password every time I add / remove / rename a folder in `/usr/local/go/src/`, so in the long run, I would like to create new project on my Desktop instead of `/usr/local/go/src/`

Comment: "should write my package on usr/local/go/src/chapter11/math/", no of course not. Just follow https://go.dev/doc/, the tutorials. It's dead simple.

Answer (score -2):

It turned out:

1. You can create the project on Desktop e.g `/Users/username/Desktop/Learn/learn-go`.
2. `go install` in the project folder e.g `/Users/username/Desktop/Learn/learn-go` will create a file on `/usr/local/go/bin`.
3. If you create a package e.g `package math` and you wish to access it, you need to run e.g `go mod init example.com/chapter11` and then you need to add `import "example.com/chapter11/math"`